# Can I modify JComboBox popup background color of an existing object?

Tags: java, swing, popup, jcombobox

I have an existing JComboBox object. I can modify many of its properties using the internal methods. However, I could not find similar methods to customize the popup's appearance - specifically, the popup's background color. I have an existing object, so I wish to use its existing methods/properties, not to write a dedicated class. Is this possible?

Note: this question is **NOT** the same as the linked question above (which incorrectly states that this question already has an answer): that question asked about the *selected item*'s bgcolor (in the combobox's editbox); I am asking about the *popup box*'s bgcolor.

Comment: My question is NOT the same as the linked question above (which incorrectly states that this question already has an answer): that question asked about the *selected item*'s bgcolor (in the combobox's editbox); I am asking about the *popup box*'s bgcolor.

Comment: The other question[1] was posted after mine - it did not exist when I posted mine. As for the answer, while the answer that I accepted does not directly answer my question (but rather the other question), it does point in the apparently correct (and presumably only) way in which to solve the problem, namely to create a dedicated cell renderer class. Nobody gave a better answer in the month since I posted my question so I decided it was close enough and accepted the answer.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412902/background-color-of-the-selected-item-in-an-uneditable-jcombobox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As eugener said, using a custom `ListCellRenderer` is definitely the right way to do this. You just need to create a class that extends `DefaultListCellRenderer`.  This default renderer extends `JLabel` so it couldn't be easier to understand!  You just need to make a call to `setBackground()`.

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" });
combo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        super.paint(g);
    }
});
```

Comment: As I noted above - I wish to avoid creating a custom class. However, since this is the best answer so far, I've accepted it - maybe there really is no other way to do what I need. Thanks to all for the efforts.

Comment: I'm glad that helps.  In a way, using an anonymous class as I have done eliminates the need to make a new Java class, which is partly what you're hinting at, but really there's no need to worry about creating a new classes _in general_.  If you need custom functionality, create a custom class to do it, so it can be reused.  That's how OOP works!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create a custom comboxbox renderer. More Information is here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

Comment: As I noted above - I wish to avoid creating a custom class. Is there any way to access the pop-up component using existing properties/methods?

Comment: That is not going to help because the default renderer will render on top of it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
comboBox.setBackground(color);
```

Comment: No that's the bg of combo itself, not the pop-up.