# JComboBox change background color

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, look-and-feel

So, I created comboBox and button near each other.
The goal is to change the background of the combo box and make it the same as in the JButton. I applied the same color for both, but this is what I get. When inactive, the color of the drop-down list and the down button is kind of gray.

[image]

When I click on the combo box, the color of the down button and the background of the list itself change to the desired one. The top fixed element became more dark gray, but it's steel with not expected color.

[image]

This is an absolutely standard combo box. Here is what I am tried to configure.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static handler.Commands.COMMANDS_ARRAY;
import static java.awt.Color.WHITE;

public class MessageComboBox extends JComboBox {

    Dimension messageComboBoxDimension = new Dimension(242, 32);

    public MessageComboBox() {
        setBackground(new Color(71, 81, 93));
        getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground(new Color(71, 81, 93));
        ((JTextField) this.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setOpaque(true);
        setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(COMMANDS_ARRAY));
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(false);
        setPreferredSize(messageComboBoxDimension);
        setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                setBackground(new Color(71, 81, 93));
                setForeground(WHITE);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make the background for JComboBox down button and fixed drop-down element the same as in JButton even when is't not focused? For some reason it is gray.

Is this related to LookAndFeel?
**__________________________________________________________________________________**

**Update:**
Issue resolved in the next topic
[LookAndFeel blocking JComboBox background change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541587/lookandfeel-blocking-jcombobox-background-change)
**__________________________________________________________________________________**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258224/change-background-color-editable-jcombobox did you try this?

Comment: @Moritz Schmidt Sure, but it doesn't work for me for a strange reason :(

Comment: Are you showing all relevant parts?

Comment: @Moritz Schmidt Yes, please check. I added new comment with pics and new code again.. But the issue is still here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
yourCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackGround(new Color(71, 81, 93))
```

works for me, active or inactive
[image]