# JComboBox - padding / spacing between arrow and label

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, nimbus

I created JComboBox and changed it background and foreground color. But I see not expected white-gray vertical line there and I don't know how to fix it. This verticl line should be painted too, but it's not.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestComboBox {

    private static final String[] ANIMALS = new String[]{"Cat", "Mouse", "Dog", "Elephant", "Bird", "Goat", "Bear"};
    private static final Color COMBO_COLOR = new Color(71, 81, 93);

    public static class MessageComboBox extends JComboBox<String> {

        public MessageComboBox(DefaultComboBoxModel model) {
            super(model);
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 50));
            setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
        }
    }

    private static class MyRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                                                      int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
                    value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            list.setBackground(COMBO_COLOR);
            list.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            list.setOpaque(false);

            return comp;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String nimbus = Arrays.asList(UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> i.getName().equals("Nimbus"))
                .findFirst()
                .get()
                .getClassName();

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(nimbus);
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.forceOpaque", false);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(800, 400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        MessageComboBox comboBox = new MessageComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel(ANIMALS));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(comboBox);
        jf.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Nimbus defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) say, the default `ComboBox.padding` is `Insets(3,3,3,3)` (See [Insets doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html)). Therefore the unexpected grey line is due to this padding. Since you want to remove the right padding, you can fix your problem by adding this line somewhere to your first `UIManager`-call:

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.padding", new Insets(3, 3, 3, 0));
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Moritz, now I understand how it works.

Comment: Your question with the color of the combobox: you might want to open another question for this, too. Iam unable to solve this problem tho.

Comment: Yep, I guess I will do it. This is just a test example for demonstration an issue here. In my main app, you know, it's visible even if I don't hover it. But before JFrame is fully loaded I see that combo box is highlighted with white color for few miliseconds and then becomes painted with expected color. I don't know ho to show it actually. Because I should paste all my code here but it's too much..

Comment: This should be no problem, since your problem is reproducible with this code snipped.