# How to change format of color in JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, tostring

I am training a GUI and am facing a string formatting problem. Don't understand how to display the colors in the list in a user-readable format?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jframe = getFrame();

        jframe.setTitle("Background color");

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        Dimension dimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();

        jframe.setBounds(dimension.width/2-250, dimension.height/2-150, 500, 300);

        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();

        JButton setColor = new JButton("Set Color");

        Color colors[] = {Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.black};
        
        JComboBox<Color> selector = new JComboBox<>(colors);

        setColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jpanel.setBackground((Color)selector.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        jpanel.add(selector);

        jpanel.add(setColor);

        jframe.add(jpanel);
        
      }

      public static JFrame getFrame() {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return jframe;
      }
  }
```

And here my output:

So, I want the name of the color to be displayed instead of java.awt.Color[.....]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyO9B.png]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a custom object to hold both the "description" and the "Color" and implement the toString() method to return the "description" value. See: [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for an example.

Comment: Are you aware of [JColorChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ColorChooserDemoProject/src/components/ColorChooserDemo.java) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258224/change-background-color-editable-jcombobox  please check  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `JComboBox` displays the value returned by the `toString` method of the objects in its list. Since your `JComboBox` contains `Color` objects, you see the value returned by method `toString` of class `java.awt.Color`.

If you want to display a color name, then you need to create a custom class that stores both the name of the color, as a `String` and the `Color` object. Then you need to override the `toString` method of the custom class to return just the name of the color. In the below code, the custom class is named `NamedColor`.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Background color");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        jframe.setBounds(dimension.width / 2 - 250, dimension.height / 2 - 150, 500, 300);
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        JButton setColor = new JButton("Set Color");
        NamedColor colors[] = {new NamedColor(Color.red, "RED"),
                               new NamedColor(Color.green, "GREEN"),
                               new NamedColor(Color.blue, "BLUE"),
                               new NamedColor(Color.black, "BLACK")};
        JComboBox<NamedColor> selector = new JComboBox<>(colors);
        setColor.addActionListener(
                  e -> jpanel.setBackground(((NamedColor) selector.getSelectedItem()).getColor()));
        jpanel.add(selector);
        jpanel.add(setColor);
        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class NamedColor {
    private Color color;
    private String name;

    public NamedColor(Color color, String name) {
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Notes regarding above code.

- The `ActionListener` interface is implemented using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- You should call method `setVisible`, of class `JFrame` only after you have added all the components.