# How to show combo box elements by clicking a button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox

I'm Using Java Swing. I have kept a Button over a Combo box because for me Coloring button is much easier than Coloring Combo box and I want that when the button is Clicked, all the Combo Box elements should Display. I have kept the combo box and button in Layered Pane and Layout is Absolute Layout.

If it is not possible, how can we change the Background Color of a Combo Box?

Comment: [Change background color editable JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258224/change-background-color-editable-jcombobox)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a minimal runnable example, I went ahead and created this GUI.

[image: Image 1]

Here's the same GUI after I left-clicked the `JButton`.

[image: Image 2]

As you can see, the `JComboBox` now has selections.

Oracle has a nifty tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will teach you how to create a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ComboBoxButton implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ComboBoxButton());
    }
    
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComboBox Button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        
        comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        panel.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private boolean firstTimeSwitch = true;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (firstTimeSwitch) {
                String[] selection = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "zeta" };
                for (int index = 0; index < selection.length; index++) {
                    comboBox.addItem(selection[index]);
                }
                
                firstTimeSwitch = false;
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```