# JCombobox hovered element not present in subclass

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I use some comboboxes in a jtable.
On the third column I needed to add tooltips in order to give addition information about the options. My problem is that I can't get to see what's the hovered element anymore.

What am I missing?

```
public class ComboBoxToolTipExample extends JComboBox {  

   String[] comboboxitems = new String[] { "A", "FC", "SN","NS", "N", "S", "FD", "FN" };
   String[] tooltip = new String[] { "Alphanumerique", "Commentaire", "Signe Numerique","Numerique Signe", "Numerique", "Signe", "Date", "Fonction Numerique" };

 public ComboBoxToolTipExample() {  
   super();

   this.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboboxitems));
   this.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());  
   this.setEnabled(true);

  }  

  class ComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {  

     public ComboBoxRenderer() {
super();
 }

   @Override  
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,  
           int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {  
       if (isSelected) {  
           setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());  
           setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());  
           if (-1 < index) {  
               list.setToolTipText(tooltip[index]);  
           }  
       } else {  
           setBackground(list.getBackground());  
           setForeground(list.getForeground());  
       }  
       setFont(list.getFont());  
       setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());  
       return this;  
   }  
   }  


   }
```

This is the result:

[image]

This is how I would like it to appear, including the tooltip:

[image]

Comment: Did you try checking `cellHasFocus` to set different colors for the cell that has the focus?

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. That is create a simple demo with a JTable and a single column with your custom renderer so we can see the behaviour when we execute the code.

Comment: Don't set the tooltip on the `JList`, set it on the `ListCellRenderer` (or more importantly, the component it returns), this is what the `JComboBox` will use to display tool tips

Comment: I solved it using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412902/background-color-of-the-selected-item-in-an-uneditable-jcombobox