# Change border cell color to all Jtable, JList when it is selected

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have a little problem with my personal look and fell, I don't want to extend MetalLookAndFeel but I want to create a pure look and feel with BasicLookAndFell.

During the development of the look and feel I realized I had a problem with the label border when a display component like a JTable, JList is selected, I get this effect here on the yellow JLabel.

I wanted to ask you now if there is a constant look and feel to change this color or say how to set the label, do you have any ideas?

thanks for your help, I will post pictures with a small demo below.

Effect with metal look and feel

[image]

Effect with personal look and feel

[image]

```
/*
 * This code is under license Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 1.0
 * <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/1.0/legalcode"></a>
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo 
 */

public class DemoLookAndFeel extends JFrame {

    static {
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MyLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DemoLookAndFeel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private JTable table;

    public void init() {
        table = new JTable();

        table.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    return "Pasta";
                }
                return "Italy";
            }
        });

        this.add(table);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyLookAndFeel extends BasicLookAndFeel {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "my look and feel";
        }

        @Override
        public String getID() {
            return "qwerty";
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DemoLookAndFeel demo = new DemoLookAndFeel();
                demo.init();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you try to change `SelectionForeground` and `SelectionBackground`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200477/change-color-of-selection-after-selection-in-a-jcombobox

Comment: yes, but the border color non changed, I do change color the border to JList because I have setting the bordert empty when I override CellRenderList, but I'm finding an method for change the color border to UIDefault with an constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the [Table.focusCellHighlightBorder](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-swing/ui-default.html) property or with [getTableCellRendererComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) similar post for this [Swing JTable - Highlight selected cell in a different color from rest of the selected row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862102/swing-jtable-highlight-selected-cell-in-a-different-color-from-rest-of-the-sel)

Example how to change the yellow border to red (the selection border)

```
UIManager.put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder",
        new BorderUIResource.LineBorderUIResource(Color.red));
```

Full code

```
/*
 * This code is under license Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 1.0
 * <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/1.0/legalcode"></a>
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */

public class DemoLookAndFeel extends JFrame {

    static {
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MyLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DemoLookAndFeel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private JTable table;

    public void init() {
        table = new JTable();

        table.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    return "Pasta";
                }
                return "Italy";
            }
        });

        this.add(table);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyLookAndFeel extends BasicLookAndFeel {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "my look and feel";
        }

        @Override
        public String getID() {
            return "qwerty";
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder",
                new BorderUIResource.LineBorderUIResource(Color.red));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DemoLookAndFeel demo = new DemoLookAndFeel();
            demo.init();
        });
    }

}
```