# How to programmatically access the display field of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, jcombobox

I would like to set foreground and/or background color of the
displayed item in a JComboBox.
From the Javadoc I can't figure out how to access that JTextField.
Thanks.
;JOOP!

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, I just can't decide which one and don't have time for cleanup now, so all you voters pick your favorite I don't want to hammer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342495/set-background-of-jcombobox-in-swing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258224/change-background-color-editable-jcombobox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412902/background-color-of-the-selected-item-in-an-uneditable-jcombobox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162980/can-i-modify-jcombobox-popup-background-color-of-an-existing-object. @Sciuriware Which of those do you like best?

Comment: The text field, fyi, is `(JTextField) theComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm very sorry that I did not search with the right keywords.
I prefer that simple one-liner above; all I needed.
Thanks again.
;JOOP!